# Display tooltips outside a PieChart in Chart.js v.2

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I made the customization explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37989832/858981 in order to always show tooltips. However, as you can see from this example, sometimes they are too close

[image: PieChart with many segments]

Is there any way to display the tooltips farther from the center, or even outside the pie?

Comment: Any luck? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, I am still looking for a solution.