# Chart.js - doughnut show active segment tooltip (on click of external button)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```
// ignore this comment - required to post the following jsfiddle.net link!
```

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/68bf25vh/

If you click a doughnut segment, the corresponding tooltip displays, which is the correct functionality.

The problem is triggering this desired functionality when a user clicks one of the buttons below the doughnut. E.g. when a user clicks the 'Trigger Segment 1 Click' button. The tooltip should display above segment 1 (just as if the user had clicked segment 1).

A bonus would be having the tooltip displaying above segment 1 initially too, but not essential.

Any help much appreciated :)

**Please note**

Using Chart.js v 2.5.0. I've read a few articles suggesting to use a showTooltip() method, e.g. chart.showTooltip([chart.segments[0]], true); Unfortunately this method does not exist in this version.

Found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37989832, but this displays all tooltips. Just want the tooltip of the active (current) segment to display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function to display corresponding tooltip, when clicked on an external button :

```
function showTooltip(chart, index) {
   var segment = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[index];
   chart.tooltip._active = [segment];
   chart.tooltip.update();
   chart.draw();
}
```

When calling the function, pass chart-instance and button-index as the first and second argument respectively.

**BONUS :**

To initially show the tooltip of segment-1, add the following config in your chart options :

```
animation: {
   onComplete: function() {
      if (!isChartRendered) {
         showTooltip(myChart, 0);
         isChartRendered = true;
      }
   }
}
```

<sup>* declare a variable named `isChartRendered` in global-scope and set it to `false`</sup>

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var isChartRendered = false;
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'doughnut',
   data: {
      labels: ['Segment 1', 'Segment 2', 'Segment 3'],
      datasets: [{
         data: [10, 10, 10]
      }]
   },
   options: {
      events: ['click'],
      cutoutPercentage: 70,
      legend: {
         display: false
      },
      tooltips: {
         displayColors: false
      },
      onClick: function(evt, elements) {},
      // BONUS: show segment 1 tooltip initially
      animation: {
         onComplete: function() {
            if (!isChartRendered) {
               showTooltip(myChart, 0);
               isChartRendered = true;
            }
         }
      }
   }
});

$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
   var $this = $(this),
       index = $this.index();
   showTooltip(myChart, index);
});

function showTooltip(chart, index) {
   var segment = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[index];
   chart.tooltip._active = [segment];
   chart.tooltip.update();
   chart.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:400px;height:400px;">
   <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:50px;">
   <button>Trigger Segment 1 Click</button>
   <button>Trigger Segment 2 Click</button>
   <button>Trigger Segment 3 Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For Chart.js 3 the GRUNT`s solution needs some modifications:

```
chart.tooltip.setActiveElements([{datasetIndex: 0, index: index}]);
chart.tooltip.update();
chart.render();
```

If you want to change also the segment style:

```
const activeSegment = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[index];
chart.updateHoverStyle([{element: activeSegment, datasetIndex: 0}], null, true);
```