# How to always show tooltip? Im using vue-chartjs v3.4

Tags: vue-chartjs

I need to always show tooltips

I tried
[How to show tooltips always on Chart.js 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241610/how-to-show-tooltips-always-on-chart-js-2)
[I want to show the value of label inside the pie graph. (vue-chartjs / pieceLabel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503137/i-want-to-show-the-value-of-label-inside-the-pie-graph-vue-chartjs-piecelabe/51504219#51504219?newreg=7da957320f70453eaccc872b6bd2f80e)
etc.

```
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Line,
  props: {
    linechartData: {
      type: Array | Object,
      required: true
    },
    linechartLabels: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'MONTHLY FEEDBACKS RECEIVED (LAST 12 MONTHS)'
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            },
            gridLines: {
              display: true
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: true
            },
            display: false
          }]
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: this.linechartLabels,
      datasets: [{
        borderColor: '#027be3',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(38, 166, 154, 0.5)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointBorderColor: '#249EBF',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(38, 166, 154, 0.5)',
        data: this.linechartData
      }]
    }, this.options)
  }
}
```

I expect tooltip to always show by default