# How can I trigger the hover mode from outside the chart with charts.js 2?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I would like to reproduce the hover behavior on multiple charts at the same time by clicking a button. I was thinking of putting the equivalent button id to the graphic labels.

[image: How it will look like]

For example, by clicking on the orange button (Cf. attached image), I get his ID and I would like to trigger the event hover in each orange item of each chart (which having a label identical to button's id).

I can detect which item has a label equivalent to my id, but I do not know how to replicate the hover's behavior on it.

Is there a way to force to set the hover mode active on an items in charts?

**MY HTML:**

```
<div class="graph">
  <canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="OCG">Test</button>
</div>
```

**MY JS:**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
var ocacolor = '#EE8B54',
    ocbcolor = '#C2B49B',
    ocbacolor = '#AECF86',
    ocgcolor = '#E97676',
    ocpcolor = '#088DA5';
var backgroundcolor = [ocacolor, ocbcolor, ocbacolor, ocgcolor, ocpcolor]

data = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [1, 1, 1, 4, 1],
        backgroundColor: backgroundcolor
    }],
    labels: [
        'OCA',
        'OCB',
        'OCBA',
        'OCG',
        'OCP'
    ]
};

//CREATING CHART
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        onClick : function(evt,dataset){
            //I GET THE LABEL TEXT OF THE CLICKED ITEM
          console.log(dataset[0]._model.label);
        }
    }
});

$("#OCG").click(function(){
  var plop = this.id
  myDoughnutChart.data.labels.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element == plop) {
      //GET THIS ITEM ID AND PUT IT ON HOVER MODE
    }
  });
})
```

Here's a fiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/8wye9vL4/28/

Comment: This is a great start, thank you! But is this a way to highlight the items like when hovering?

Comment: @gaetanoM
I did a little modification, hover the button instead of clicking, and i would like that after hoovering the button, the chart has the same behavior as at the initialisation. Because here, the tooltips doesn't appear anymore after interact with the button.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wye9vL4/55/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to show a tooltip for a specific element by clicking on a button you may take a look to [github](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2850) or [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992922/chart-js-v2-how-to-make-tooltips-always-appear-on-pie-chart)

I changed a bit the code I found there just to let you show a tooltip on button click.

I added a property to your options in Chartjs:

```
showMyTooltips: '',
```

This must contain the index of the tooltip to be shown. This value is used inside the registered plugin like in the example code whose links are reported  in this answer.

Here is the snippet:

```js
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeRender: function (chart) {
        if (!!chart.config.options.showMyTooltips && chart.config.options.showMyTooltips.trim().length != 0) {
            chart.pluginTooltips = [];
            chart.config.options.showMyTooltips.trim().split(',').forEach(function (ele, idx) {
                var sector = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[ele];
                chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                    _chart: chart.chart,
                    _chartInstance: chart,
                    _data: chart.data,
                    _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                    _active: [sector]
                }, chart));
            });
        }
    },
    afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
        if (chart.config.options.showMyTooltips) {
            // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
            if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
                if (easing !== 1)
                    return;
                chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
            }
            Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function (tooltip) {
                tooltip.initialize();
                tooltip.update();
                // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
                tooltip.pivot();
                tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
            });
        }
    }
});

var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
var ocacolor = '#EE8B54',
        ocbcolor = '#C2B49B',
        ocbacolor = '#AECF86',
        ocgcolor = '#E97676',
        ocpcolor = '#088DA5';
var backgroundcolor = [ocacolor, ocbcolor, ocbacolor, ocgcolor, ocpcolor]

data = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [5, 2, 3, 9, 2],
        backgroundColor: backgroundcolor
    }],
    labels: [
        'OCA',
        'OCB',
        'OCBA',
        'OCG',
        'OCP'
    ]
};
//CREATING CHART
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        showMyTooltips: '',
        onClick: function (evt, dataset) {
            //I GET THE LABEL TEXT OF THE CLICKED ITEM
            console.log(dataset[0]._model.label);
        }
    }
});

$(":radio").on('change', function (e) {
    myDoughnutChart.options.showMyTooltips = myDoughnutChart.data.labels.indexOf(this.id).toString();
    myDoughnutChart.update(true);
})
```

```css
.graph{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>


<div class="graph">
    <canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="OCA" autocomplete="off"> Test OCA
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="OCB" autocomplete="off"> Test OCB
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="OCBA" autocomplete="off"> Test OCBA
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="OCG" autocomplete="off"> Test OCG
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="OCP" autocomplete="off"> Test OCP
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the links, I managed to find out how to highlight the items.
Your example shows how to display tooltips by clicking, but I would like to be able to reset the tooltip so that it is displayed normally when hovering the chart.
If you look at my example, after hoovering i try:
myDoughnutChart.options.showMyTooltips = '';
    myDoughnutChart.update();

but that's not working. Any idea of how reset the chart and the tooltip like at the start?

Comment: Pass **true** to the update method. Please, take a look to the snippet. I updated it. Let me know and thanks

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!
[My fiddle with both tootltip and highlight for those who need](https://jsfiddle.net/8wye9vL4/71/)