# Chartjs v2.8 showAllTooltips does not exist

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I have a chart being created using chart.js version 2.8 running on an Angular application. I need the tooltips to always be visible on the chart by default and not just when the mouse is hovering over the points (the chart is a scatter plot). I have looked into how to set this up and most sources seem to recommend using the pluginService to register a fix to enable the possibility. However chart.config.options.showAllTooltips needs to already exist whereas it just doesn't seem to in chart.js v2.8 anymore.

```
this.LQChart = new Chart(this.myChart, {
                type: 'bubble',
                data: {
                    labels:['Jobs']
                }, options: {
                    plugins:{
                        colorschemes: {
                            scheme: 'brewer.YlOrBr9'
                        },
                        zoom:{
                            pan: {
                                enabled: true,
                                mode: 'xy',
                                rangeMin: {
                                    x: null,
                                    y: null
                                },
                                rangeMax:{
                                    x: null,
                                    y: null
                                }
                            },
                            zoom:{
                                enabled: true,
                                drag: false,
                                mode:'xy',
                                rangeMin: {
                                    x: null,
                                    y: null
                                },
                                rangeMax:{
                                    x: null,
                                    y: null
                                },
                                speed:0.1
                            }
                        },
                        // datalabels: {
                        //     color: 'white',
                        //     font: {
                        //         weight:'bold'
                        //     },
                        //     display: function (context) {
                        //         console.log("Algo: "+context);
                        //         return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] > 15;
                        //     },
                        //     formatter: function(value, context) {
                        //         console.log("Forma: "+value+" : "+context);
                        //         return context.dataIndex + ':' + Math.round(value*100) + '%';
                        //     }
                        // }
                    }, tooltips: {
                        callbacks: {
                            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                                var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                                return label
                            }
                        }
                    },legend: {
                        display: false
                    }, title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Location Quotient of Jobs in Region'
                    }, scales: {
                        yAxes: [{ 
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: "# of Jobs"
                            },
                            id:'y-axis-0',
                            type:'linear',
                            gridLines: {
                                display:true
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                    return Number(value.toString());
                                }
                            },
                            position:'left'
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: "LQ"
                            },
                            id: 'x-axis-0',
                            type: 'linear',
                            position: 'bottom',
                        }]
                    }, annotation: {
                        annotations: [{
                            borderColor: 'black',
                            //borderDash: [2, 2],
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            mode: 'vertical',
                            type: 'line',
                            value: 1.0,
                            scaleID: 'x-axis-0'
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is the code I am using to create my chart, I just need to know how to set chart tooltips to always visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been many discussions around this issue in V2 of ChartJs which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992922/chart-js-v2-how-to-make-tooltips-always-appear-on-pie-chart), [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1861) and [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/940).

Overall, what you need to do is register your own plugin for ChartJs which you can then use via the `options` property.

So if you add the following plugin registration:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
            beforeRender: function (chart) {
                if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
                    // create an array of tooltips
                    // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
                    chart.pluginTooltips = [];
                    chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (sector, j) {
                            chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                                _chart: chart.chart,
                                _chartInstance: chart,
                                _data: chart.data,
                                _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                                _active: [sector]
                            }, chart));
                        });
                    });

                    // turn off normal tooltips
                    chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
                }
            },
            afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
                if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
                    // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
                    if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
                        if (easing !== 1)
                            return;
                        chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
                    }

                    // turn on tooltips
                    chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
                    Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function (tooltip) {
                        tooltip.initialize();
                        tooltip.update();
                        // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
                        tooltip.pivot();
                        tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
                    });
                    chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
                }
            }
        })
```

Then you can add the `showAllTooltips` property in your `options` like so:

```
options: {
        showAllTooltips: true
        ...
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-hwscc5) illustration of your code with some sample data.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was talking about. This solution is what I encountered before. When I try to put it into the code I get the following errors:

`if(chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {`
gives me: "Property 'showAllTooltips' does not exist on type 'ChartOptions'."

`chart.pluginTooltips` 
gives me "Property 'pluginTooltips' does not exist on type 'Chart'."

`chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltips({...}));`
gives me: "Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature."

among others

Comment: Did you take a look at how I've done it in the StackBlitz in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did. Now I've done some playing with it and I am still getting all of the errors that I mentioned. In fact my code in Visual Studio Code is just littered with red lines and error warning. However when I press 'run' it all works fine and displays the tooltips by default exactly as I wanted. I will mark the issue as solved for now. Thank you for your help. I just need to figure out why I'm seeing errors where there are none.

Comment: Sounds like all your error are due to the typings, i.e. vscode thinks the properties don't exist on your specified types.

Comment: I've done some reformatting and removed most of them. Two errors remain though. At `new Chart.Tooltip({...})` it still gives me "Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature." And at `easing !== 1` it gives me "This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'Easing' and '1' have no overlap."

Comment: Define `easing` as `any` in the `afterDraw` function and do the same with `Chart`, i.e. `new (Chart as any).Tooltip({...`

Comment: Finally got it sorted. Final code posted in the next answer. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Viqas definitely gave me the right answer but I wanted to amend the following:
If anyone is having the same issue that I was having where the pluginService.register code throws all manner of errors I want to post here my register code after modification:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeRender: function (chart) {
        if (chart.config.options['showAllTooltips']) {
            // create an array of tooltips
            // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
            chart['pluginTooltips'] = [];
            chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (sector, j) {
                    chart['pluginTooltips'].push(new (Chart as any).Tooltip({
                        _chart: chart['chart'],
                        _chartInstance: chart,
                        _data: chart.data,
                        _options: chart['options']['tooltips'],
                        _active: [sector]
                    }, chart));
                });
            });

            // turn off normal tooltips
            chart['options']['tooltips']['enabled'] = false;
        }
    },
    afterDraw: function (chart, easing: any) {
        if (chart.config.options['showAllTooltips']) {
            // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
            if (!chart['allTooltipsOnce']) {
                if (easing !== 1)
                    return;
                chart['allTooltipsOnce'] = true;
            }

            // turn on tooltips
            chart['options']['tooltips']['enabled'] = true;
            Chart.helpers.each(chart['pluginTooltips'], function (tooltip) {
                tooltip.initialize();
                tooltip.update();
                // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
                tooltip.pivot();
                tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
            });
            chart['options']['tooltips']['enabled'] = false;
        }
    }
})
```

This worked for me and I hope anyone else who runs into the same issue will find it helpful.