# Chart.js v2: How to make tooltips always appear on line chart?

Tags: chart.js

I have searched through for the solution but I have found solution to pie charts only. For example this one : [Chart.js v2: How to make tooltips always appear on pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992922/chart-js-v2-how-to-make-tooltips-always-appear-on-pie-chart)

I just want make the tooltip visible without hovering. I have tried registering new pluginService but its not working and its producing this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

this is what I have so far

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
            beforeRender: function (chart) {
                if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
                    // create an array of tooltips
                    // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
                    chart.pluginTooltips = [];
                    chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (sector, j) {
                            chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                                _chart: chart.chart,
                                _chartInstance: chart,
                                _data: chart.data,
                                _options: chart.options,
                                _active: [sector]
                            }, chart));
                        });
                    });

                    // turn off normal tooltips
                    chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
                }
            },
            afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
                if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
                    // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
                    if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
                        if (easing !== 1)
                            return;
                        chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
                    }

                    // turn on tooltips
                    chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
                    Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function (tooltip) {
                        tooltip.initialize();
                        tooltip.update();
                        // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
                        tooltip.pivot();
                        tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
                    });
                    chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
                }
            }
        })


var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
  }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
        showAllTooltips: true
    }
});
```

appreciate any helps tq

Answer (score 1):

When using the latest stable version of Chart.js (2.9.3), it works with the following changes.

1. Instead of `Chart.pluginService.register`, use [`Chart.plugin.register`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html)
2. Instead of `change _options : chart.options` write `_options : chart.options.tooltips`

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
Chart.plugins.register({
  beforeRender: function(chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      // create an array of tooltips, 
      // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
      chart.pluginTooltips = [];
      chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function(sector, j) {
          chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
            _chart: chart.chart,
            _chartInstance: chart,
            _data: chart.data,
            _options: chart.options.tooltips,
            _active: [sector]
          }, chart));
        });
      });      
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false; // turn off normal tooltips
    }
  },
  afterDraw: function(chart, easing) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
        if (easing !== 1) {
          return;
        }
        chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
      }
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
      Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
        tooltip.initialize();
        tooltip.update();
        tooltip.pivot();
        tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
      });
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  }
});

new Chart("chart", {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    },
    showAllTooltips: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: how can we show it on specific data point? for example only for `April` on load.