# How to get all tooltips to show with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Chart.js allows you to show tooltips like this:

[image]

This is explained in the official docs here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/tooltip/content.html

My question is: How can I make all tooltips show at the same time? So instead of having to hover, the tooltip for every point is visible.

Is this something that's possible using Chart.js?

Comment: No this is not possible by default, you will need to write your own custom plugin to achieve this

Comment: This answer shows how to solve your issue with Chart.js v2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61436881/2358409