# PrimeNG PIE chart values are not displayed on Slice - how to show values on default load instead of hover over

Tags: angular, label, primeng, pie-chart

[image]

front end

```
<td>
  <div class="p-col-8 ui-toolbar-group-right">

    <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-search" (click)="populate_charts()"></button>

  </div>
</td>
```

TS-File

```
this.pieOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  labels: {
    render: 'label'
  },


  legend: {
    position: 'right',

  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'sample chart',
    fontSize: 16
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeNG charts are based on chart.js https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

So basically you are looking for a solution for that.
Luckely there is already a SO thread - the answer seems to be a bit more complex than just enabling one option though.

[Chart.js v2: How to make tooltips always appear on pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992922/chart-js-v2-how-to-make-tooltips-always-appear-on-pie-chart)

Comment: i need enable for all tooltips answer is not that complex.secondly can you help where to change the code as i am already using latest version of chart.js