# How to show data on pie chart in angular 2 using ng2-charts?

Tags: angular, typescript

As in fig I can implement pie chart but how to show data on chart

[image]

like this:

[image]

```
<canvas baseChart  class="pie"
  [data]="Data"
  [labels]="Labels"
  [colors]="Colors"
  [chartType]="pieChartType">
</canvas>

 public Labels:string[]=['Female','Male'];
 public Data:any =[51,30];
 public pieChartType:string = 'pie';
 public Colors:any = 
 [
{
  backgroundColor: [      
  'green',
  'red'
  ]
  }
];
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to run two npm command

```
npm install ng2-charts --save

npm install chart.js --save
```

Important: Embedding Chart.js in application is mandatory! in your index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

Import this one on App.module.ts

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
imports: [ChartsModule]
```

Component.html

```
<div style="display: block">
  <canvas baseChart
          [data]="pieChartData"
          [labels]="pieChartLabels"
          [chartType]="pieChartType"
          (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
          (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

Component.ts

```
public pieChartLabels: string[] = ['Male', 'Female'];
  public pieChartData: number[] = [51, 30];
  public pieChartType: any = 'pie';

  // events
  public chartClicked(e: any): void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e: any): void {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

this code is working as you expect.

Comment: My code is working . It's drawing chart but I don't know what are the  options there for display data on chart. which I put in fig 2

Comment: `public Data:any =[51,30];` this is display on your screen if you are increase value of array i.e. 'public Data:any =[51,30,19];' that data is show three parts of pie  charts. if learn more of Angular2-charts go through [link](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)

Comment: I applied changes but it's not displaying number on chart

Comment: @Shaktishah can you share your code with [link] (https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ym9dzm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html  Code is here

Comment: here it is showing data when we move cursor on chart but in my code it not showing and here I wrote same code so what is the problem here

Comment: Is there any other option for display data on chart ??

Comment: @HetalAhir Sorry for late i'm busy in some other work. there is two way to handle this first one is include Tooltip library link  (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/802), and second one is custom link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524295/how-to-add-label-in-chart-js-for-pie-chart/24755401),

Comment: it's in javascript not in typescript

Comment: And it's for lable and I want both label and number on it's respective part on pie chart

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/doughnut-chart-6iuguq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts    reference to this it is showing data but I am receiving data from another component so I have to write   public pieChartData: number[] = [51, 30];
 this line In Docheck() method otherwise it gives zero value so when I write  public pieChartData: number[] = [51, 30];
 this line in do check method data is not showing on chart so please can anyone help me